# centre title in PDF converted from markdown using Pandoc

Tags: r, markdown, pandoc

I'm converting a markdown document to a PDF document using Pandoc from within R. I'm trying to centre the title.

So far, I've tried:

```
 <center># This is my title</center>
```

and

```
-># This is my title<-
```

but neither have worked. Is there a way to centre the title when converting from markdown to PDF using Pandoc?

Comment: The position (alignment) of the title(s) depends on the LaTeX stylesheet/template you are using (see the `--template` parameter of `pandoc`), not on the markdown bits. Or you can manually add some LaTeX syntax (e.g. `\begin{center}...\end{center}`) in your markdown file.

Comment: This latex code worked: \begin{center}
  \fontsize{16}{36}\selectfont
  \textbf{This is my title}
\end{center}. Didn't realise you could mix and match latex and markdown. Please convert comment to answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`pandoc` has [its own extended version of markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#pandocs-markdown). This includes a [title block](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#title-block).

If the file begins with a title block

```
% my title
% Me; Someone else
% May 2013
```

This will be parsed into `LaTeX` and the resulting `pdf` as

```
\title{my title}
\author{Me \and Someone Else}
\date{May 2013}
```

and then `

```
\maketitle
```

called within the document.

This will create the standard centred title.

If you want to change how the title etc is formatted you could use the [titling package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titling).

If you want to change how the section headers are formatted, you could use the [titlesec package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec).

To automagically have pandoc implement these you could define [your own template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates). A simpler option is to have a file with your desired latex preamble to be included in the header. and then use the appropriate arguments when calling `pandoc` (eg `-H FILE`  or  `--include-in-header=FILE`)